# Number of actual printed lines in code blocks output console (fortran compiler)

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

Why the output console of code blocks displays only the last 25 printed lines, although my code is written to print "hello world" for 60 times for example? This is my code:

```
program hello

implicit none
integer i

do i=1,60
print *, i, "hello world"
end do

end program
```

Comment: Welcome, I strongly suggest taking the welcome [tour]. It shows how to use this site.

Comment: It seems you will have to find out how to set the line limit in the console of CodeBlocks. Or run your code in a different console that has a higher limit.